# Convert ISO 8601 datetime to Jira compatible datetime format

Tags: python, datetime, jira, iso8601

The JIRA REST API is peculiar and picky about date and time strings. It's not fully compliant with ISO 8601.

For example:

ISO Compliant Datetime:     `2023-06-25T20:32:13+00:00`

Jira Compatible Datetime:   `2023-06-25T20:32:13.00+0000`

Below are the 2 changes in ISO format for Jira Compatibility,

1. Time zone offsets in the form `[+-]hhmm` instead of the ISO format, `[+-]hh:mm`.
2. It needs fractional seconds, even if that fraction is 0 (e.g. `2023-06-25T20:32:13+0000` is not accepted while `2023-06-25T20:32:13.00+0000` is accepted).

Below python code gives me the Jira compatible value but can this is achieved in a more pythonic way or are there some libraries which can do this for me?

```
import datetime

planned_finish_date = (datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc) + datetime.timedelta(hours=5)).isoformat(sep='T', timespec='seconds')

planned_finish_date = planned_finish_date.rsplit("+", 1)[0] + ".00+" + planned_finish_date.rsplit("+", 1)[1].replace(":", "")
```

Comment: Looks like this is a [bug ignored for 5 years](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRASERVER-61378). One of the suggested fixes is `parse($date_value).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000+0000')`

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you need ISO format ([RFC3339](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3339)), but with fractional seconds being mandatory and without a colon between hours and minutes of the UTC offset (see also Kanavos Panagiotis' comment).

Assuming your input string is guaranteed to have a UTC offset (tz specified), I'd choose a different `timespec` (milli- or micorseconds) for `isoformat`, then slice the string to remove the last colon:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timezone

now_iso = datetime.now(timezone.utc).isoformat(timespec="microseconds")
print(now_iso)
# 2023-06-26T05:52:25.134221+00:00

now_jira = now_iso[:-3] + now_iso[-2:]
print(now_jira)
# 2023-06-26T05:52:25.134221+0000
```

Note that this is only a safe approach if you can assert a UTC offset, e.g. by making sure that the `tzinfo` property of a datetime object is not None:

```py
dt = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
assert dt.tzinfo is not None, "must use timezone-aware datetime"

# then
now_iso = dt.isoformat(timespec="microseconds")
now_jira = now_iso[:-3] + now_iso[-2:]
```

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for the comment; my apologies, I'm not familiar with JIRA. So, IIUC they follow the JSON convention, however I think [RFC3339](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3339) does include the colon in the UTC offset?

Comment: My comment was wrong. I didn't notice the offset. Guess my mind couldn't see such a glaring bug. [This is a known bug](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRASERVER-61378) that's simply not getting fixed for over 5 years! One of the workarounds just ignores fractional seconds `parse($date_value).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000+0000')`.